# Fill data frame rows with vectors of varying column subsets of all columns in the data frame

Tags: r

Say I initialize an empty data frame like so:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 0))
colnames(df) <- c("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5")
```

And wish to populate the data frame rows with vectors such as

```
v1 =
c2 c3 c4                
6  4  3

v2 =
c1 c3 c5                
2  5  7
```

So that `df` will look like

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
0  6  4  3  0
2  0  5  0  7
```

What's the most efficient way to go about this? The vectors are originally lists, which I was converting to a matrix and attempting to append `df` with so that the column labels are maintained throughout. However, I'm struggling to find an automated way to fill the missing element values since the columns themselves don't exist (ie v1 has no "c1" column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
df[1L, c('c2', 'c3', 'c4')] = v1
df[2L, c('c1', 'c3', 'c5')] = v2
df[is.na(df)] = 0
```

If your vectors are named, it’s even easier:

```
df[1L, names(v1)] = v1
df[2L, names(v2)] = v2
df[is.na(df)] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your vectors are still named lists, like

```
v1 <- as.list(setNames(c(6,4,3),c("c2","c3","c4")))
v2 <- as.list(setNames(c(6,4,3),c("c1","c3","c5")))
```

(so you don't have to do the step of processing them to vectors), you can use

```
df = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 0))
colnames(df) <- c("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5")

listOfNamedValueLists <- list(v1,v2)
df <- do.call(plyr::rbind.fill,c(list(df),lapply(listOfNamedValueLists,data.frame)))
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

Note that appending `df` to the list as first element ensures you that the names are in right order.